# rabbitMQ unit tests with amqplib-mocks library

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, rabbitmq, node-amqplib

I am trying to write unit tests with [amqplib-mocks](https://github.com/Bunk/amqplib-mocks) but i can not consume message from consumer, i am getting undefined and i try to debug but not successfull.

```
describe("Rabbitmq testing Server", () => {
    let connection, channel;

    before(async () => {
        connection = await amqplib.connect("amqp://localhost");
        channel = await connection.createChannel();

        await channel.assertExchange(messagesExchange, exchangeType);

        isCreated = await channel.assertQueue(queue);
        isCreated.queue ? console.log('queue created') : 'Queue not created or already exist';

        await channel.bindQueue(queue, messagesExchange, routingKey);

        const isPublish = channel.publish(messagesExchange, routingKey, Buffer.from('should pass test')).valueOf();
        isPublish ? console.log('message published successfully') : 'message not published';
    });

    it("should create the channel", () => {
        assert.isObject(channel);
    });

    it("should register the method call", () => {
        expect(connection.createChannel()).to.have.been.all.keys;
        expect(connection.createChannel()).to.have.been.all.members;
    });

    it("should consumer consume message from queue", async () => {
        let result: string;
        const consumer = await channel.consume(queue, (msg) => {
            result = msg.content.toString();
            console.log(result);
        }, { noAck: true });

        // expect(result).to.be.equal(JSON.stringify({ success: true }));
    });

    after(() => {
        amqplib.reset();
    })
```

first two tests are passing but third test getting undefined value. Any help would be appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the `result` is not being returned before the `expect` is executed.

What's happening in your code above is

1. the `channel.consume` is being executed
2. the `expect` statement is being executed
3. the callback is being executed - `msg.content.toString()`
4. the `console.log(result)` is being executed.

What you could try is putting the `expect` inside your callback and using [`done`](https://jestjs.io/docs/asynchronous) to declare when your test has completed:

```
it("should consumer consume message from queue", async (done) => {
      let result: string;
      const consumer = await channel.consume(queue, (msg) => {
        result = msg.content.toString();
        console.log(result);
        expect(result).to.be.equal(JSON.stringify({ success: true }));        
        done();
      }, { noAck: true });
});
```